# eshell environmental variable not appearing in eshell

Tags: variables, emacs, eshell

I'm having a go with emacs and as part of that I've started using eshell. One thing I do regularly in a shell is maven builds.  For this I need certain environmental variables to be set.  I have set an environmental var with setenv in my .emacs file and when I do C-x getnev I can see it.  However if I call echo $MY_VAR in eshell I get nothing, can anyone help?

Comment: I'm using GNU Emacs 24.2.1 on Mac OS X Mountain Lion and it is working in eshell just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should set env variables in a `bat` or `sh` file which launches emacs. In this case the variables will be visible in eshell.

Comment: well, the vars are set in the shell I launch emacs from (in my bashrc file) and they're set in emacs itself, I've just checked and they're set in emacs shell (C-x shell) but not in emacs eshell (C-x eshell)...

Comment: It works in my Emacs eshell on Windows but I don't have a unix computer right now to check

Comment: I'm using GNU Emacs 24.1.1 on mac os by the way, thanks for trying.  As I said, there's not much info on the web about eshell.